# Does an include execute the PHP code of the included file?

Tags: php

If it does, is this code executed before the code of the file in which it is included or is it executed paralelly?

Comment: *How are you including...* ? There are a LOT of different ways to "include" something into something else. Some of which do, and some of which do not execute.

Comment: There is are really easy way to find out... test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things i'm missing from the question, but basically, yes. PHP will execute code inside of the PHP file if included, that is what PHP does. it executes to output code to the browser. If you do not want it to execute the code, I would suggest wrapping it in a function or sending an ajax call to the page when you are ready to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

It evaluates all the php file in the line you write the `include`.

Here's a piece of the manual:

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable
>   scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available
>   at that line in the calling file will be available within the called
>   file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes
>   defined in the included file have the global scope.

For more info: [include manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)